# Jackson JSON Provider ignoring @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson

I have a JAX-RS service for accessing some data. There are links to other classes, which I annotate with `@JsonIgnore`. Now, the Jackson provider is ignoring those annotations.

My Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
@XmlRootElement
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "version")
    private String version;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
    @Column(name = "document_number")
    private String documentNumber;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "document_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date documentDate;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "subDocument", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SubDocument> subDocumentList;

    public Document() {
    }

    public Document(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Document(Integer id, String version, String documentNumber, Date documentDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
        this.documentNumber = documentNumber;
        this.documentDate = documentDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(required = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    public String getDocumentNumber() {
        return documentNumber;
    }

    public void setDocumentNumber(String documentNumber) {
        this.documentNumber = documentNumber;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    public Date getDocumentDate() {
        return documentDate;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
    public void setDocumentDate(Date documentDate) {
        this.documentDate = documentDate;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<SubDocument> getSubDocumentList() {
        return subDocumentList;
    }

    public void setSubDocumentList(List<SubDocument> subDocumentList) {
        this.subDocumentList = subDocumentList;
    }
}
```

The REST ApplicationConfig

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    try {
        Class jacksonProvider = Class.forName("org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider");
        resources.add(jacksonProvider);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        SLOGGER.fatal("could not find class JacksonJsonProvider", ex);
    }
    addMyOtherResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}
```

And the REST Interface:

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("getDocumentById/{id}")
public Document getDocumentById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return sbDocuments.getDocumentById(id);
}
```

So, even though the `@JsonIgnore` annotation is present on my document, the list does get mapped to the output. It does work with the `@XmlTransient` annotation, but since JAXB get's used aswell, I can't add that annotation.

I use the Codehaus implementation, but I've tried FasterXML aswell, both the same result. What should I do to fix this? Service is running on a Glassfish 4.1 server.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Glassfish. Though Glassfish has the Jackson provider library, it uses MOXy as the default provider. So it is actually MOXy that is doing the serialization, not Jackson. If you want to disable MOXy, then set the property `jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson` to true. You can override `Map<String, String> getProperties()` in the `Application` subclass. If you do this, then you will need to use the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` then instead of `JacksonJsonProvider` if you want support for JAXB annotations

Comment: I've tried that, but then I need to add a Jackson-XC dependency. When I do that, it just returns the same result as before. In the meantime, I've added @JsonIgnore on the field, getter and setter.

Comment: I encounter the very same issue! (using fasterxml). I can put @JsonIgnore at the member, getter and setter - jax-rs still tries to map (and raises an invalid-json exception, for the member's type is not designed for json). Interestingly, the same code (i.e. the same object with the @JsonIgnore) works fine, when I pass it to an object mapper. So I assume it must be something in the jax-rs causing the trouble.

Comment: @Erates any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Place the @JsonIgnore above the field attribute rather than on the getter method.
i.e.

```
@JsonIgnore
private List<SubDocument> subDocumentList;
```

Comment: Tried that, now I have the @JsonIgnore on the field, getter and setter. Still outputs it.